# Getting error trying to complete Pagel's method

Tags: r

I am trying to do Pagel's method analysis and I keep running across the same error code. I have tried removing `NA` values and nothing seems to work.

```
library(phytools)
library(ape)
library(geiger)

EQ_Sociality.fit <- fitPagel(tree, EQ, Sociality)

# Error in if (xi > xj) 1L else -1L : missing value where TRUE/FALSE # needed
# In addition: Warning messages:
# 1: In xtfrm.data.frame(x) : cannot xtfrm data frames
# 2: In Ops.factor(xi, xj) : ‘>’ not meaningful for factors
```

##### Data:

```
d <- structure(list(DataPagels.EQ = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), 
    DataPagels.Sociality = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, NA, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, NA, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Eusocial", "Non-eusocial"), class = "factor")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -175L))
```

Comment: I might guess that you are providing incorrect arguments to `fitPagel`,  so a variable of class `factor` is being fed to `Ops.factor` when it shouldn't.  The output may be empty or `NULL` or something which leads to the `xi` and `xj` not having numeric values , causing the error message.    Check the man pages for all these functions,  and also re-run that line of code, then type `traceback()` so get a hint as to the location of the problem(s)